# Request structure to get signer details, docusign URL, opt out request from our side

Tags: docusignapi

I want request structure for following cases. We initiate request to your API to get below cases.

1 - Signer details - we want to fetch signer details with their status for envelope.

2 - Signer URL - we want to get signer URL for envelope. By this url, we use this URL and redirect user to signed document.

3 - Opt Out - we want generate request from our system to opt out for any envelope.

I need request sample and API like I use https://demo.docusign.net/restapi to send request to sign document. We prefer to use JSON base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do #1 and #2, there's no way that I know of to do #3.

#1 - GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients would get you the information you need for the envelope if you know the envelopeID (GUID)

#2 - [POST](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) to POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient will return your URL for the recipient to sign. You need to provide in the body:

```
{
  "clientUserId": "sample string 1",
  "userId": "sample string 2",
  "userName": "sample string 3",
  "email": "sample string 4",
  "recipientId": "sample string 5",
  "returnUrl": "sample string 6",
  "authenticationMethod": "sample string 9",
  ]
}
```

#3 you do a #1 - PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId} to void this envelope by providing this body:

```
{
  "status": "voided",
  "voidedReason": "The reason for voiding the envelope"
}
```

Comment: I researched on docusign web site https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/. I found answer about my point #3 that we say void or decline in your terminology for envelop. I found API below (PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}).                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                      For #1 - GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

Comment: I refer link https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes. which provide me all details.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood #3, it's for a specific envelope, not all envelopes

Comment: I updated the answer for #3, would you mind marking it as answered?

Comment: please help me on below query.                            
        
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032618/signer-url-for-an-envelope-calling-docusign-api-and-getting-400-bad-request-er/63042323#63042323