# Signer URL for an envelope - calling docusign API and getting 400 bad request error

Tags: docusignapi

For requirement - Signer URL - we want to get signer URL for envelope. Calling below API and but API throw 400 bad request message.

POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient

I tried with following both request.

```
{"clientUserId":"fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765-cb8b0e011ee4","userId":"fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765-cb8b0e011ee4","userName":"Manoj Sharma","email":"abc@xyz.com","recipientId":"1","authenticationMethod":"None"}
```

OR

```
{"clientUserId":"fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765-cb8b0e011ee4","email":"abc1@xyz.com","recipientId":"2","authenticationMethod":"None"}
```

Comment: Now my new request body                                                                
    {"clientUserId":"fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765- 
    cb8b0e011ee4","userName":"Manoj 
    Sharma","email":"manoj.sharma@ebix.com", 
 "recipientId":"1 
","returnUrl":"https://www.docuisgn.com","authenticationMethod":"Password"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a look at some of your recent traffic, I see a combination of errors relating to a missing returnUrl or userName.

I don't believe the userId (not the clientUserId) is required for this call, so you may want to remove that portion as well if this doesn't work.

Try changing it to:

```
{
    "clientUserId": "fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765-cb8b0e011ee4",
    "userId": "fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765-cb8b0e011ee4",
    "userName": "Manoj Sharma",
    "email": "manoj.sharma@ebix.com",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "authenticationMethod": "None",
    "returnUrl":"https://www.docuisgn.com"
}
```

If the other required details in the call are present it should start working. Let us know if you still see an error message.

Edit:

The issue is two-parts.

1. When your envelopes are being created, you're not supplying a clientUserId for the recipient. The ID can be a combination of numbers or letters, usually less than 12 characters long.
2. When you're creating the request for the recipientViewToken, the clientUserId you're specifying is the apiUserName of the intended recipient. The apiUserName is a user-specific GUID that's assigned to a specific user on your account. In order for the recipientViewToken requests to go through, the clientUserId needs to match up between the recipient already present on the envelope and the user details you specify in the call, which is agnostic of this APIUserName.

Your example:

```
{
    "clientUserId": "fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765-cb8b0e011ee4",
    "userId": "fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765-cb8b0e011ee4",
    "userName": "Manoj Sharma",
    "email": "manoj.sharma@ebix.com",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "authenticationMethod": "None",
    "returnUrl": "https://www.docuisgn.com"
}
```

Will most likely work if you change it to:

```
{
    "userName": "Manoj Sharma",
    "email": "manoj.sharma@ebix.com",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "authenticationMethod": "None",
    "returnUrl": "https://www.docuisgn.com"
}
```

However, if you intend for your recipients to be captive, you just need to supply the same `clientUserId` in the envelope definitions that you do when requesting the token. It doesn't have to be an APIUsername, it can be as simple as 5678.

Comment: No this is not working. Getting same error. I understanding there are some issues on request body parameter values. But what is wrong, I am looking for

Comment: @ManojK.S.can you try to get API logs and send to me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com ? to do that go on the top-right name menu to "Preferences" and click "Security and Privacy" and then scroll down to enable API logs. Then do the same thing again, download the logs and email them. Matt and I will help you out

Comment: Thanks @InbarGazit. I have sent you email of logs. Please check your inbox and you have email from "Manoj Sharma" under this subject.

Comment: Thank you @ManojK.S. Please see my response appended to the original answer.

Comment: Thanks @MattKing. It is working if I remove clientUserId & userId from request body. Is right to use without clientUserId/client? , As you suggested, using following request working for me.    { "userName": "Manoj Sharma", "email": "manoj.sharma@ebix.com", "recipientId": "1", "authenticationMethod": "None", "returnUrl": "https://www.docuisgn.com" }

Comment: Hi @ManojK.S. Happy to help! The userId won't be required, the way you have this set up right now is the same as if a person click on a Review Documents notification they received in an email. If you add a ClientUserId (IE: 1001) to the recipient definitions and use the same value for the ClientUserId when requesting your recipientToken, you can also avoid the email messages going out to that recipient.

The workflow you have here is viable, if you'd like to continue discussing I'd recommend reaching out to our Customer Support group to discuss available alternatives.