# Implemented JWT - The user ID of the user to be impersonated

Tags: docusignapi

We are developing application for e-signature on PDF for different users of oru system, which call many docusign APIs and  we try use JWT to authenticate the APIs. I able to get token. But I have doubt on one parameter of JWT request body. I refer link https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken.

What do you mean by "The user ID of the user to be impersonated.", I used API account user id.

[image]

Please refer my previous query [Signer URL for an envelope - calling docusign API and getting 400 bad request error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032618/signer-url-for-an-envelope-calling-docusign-api-and-getting-400-bad-request-er).  I think, this is not correct what I use to pass here. However I am getting token.

Please let me know if you want to know more details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

"The user ID of the user to be impersonated." means exactly this, you can impersonate a user or "*act on behalf of the user*" by providing his userId in the JWT call.
So the impersonated user will be the sender of the envelope.
If you use your account userId you will be acting as the sender

Comment: No, actually this is not clear to me. please provide some example. I thing wording written into query of stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032618/signer-url-for-an-envelope-calling-docusign-api-and-getting-400-bad-request-er

Comment: Did you mean client user id one of the user from recipients?

Comment: Hi @ManojKS please read this guide. It explains what JWT is and when to use it https://developers.docusign.com/docs/platform/auth/jwt. In https://github.com/docusign we have 31 examples for 6 languages. Every one of them is using both Authentication Code Grant and JWT

Comment: same thing written as you said in your answer. Leave it now.